# How to return a specific type of object property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, object, keyof

Lets say I have a list of flags in an object as below:

```
type Flags = {
  flag1: string,
  flag2: string,
  flag3: boolean,
  flag4: number
}

// const myFlags: Flags = {
//   flag1: 'value 1',
//   flag2: 'value 1',
//   flag3: true,
//   flag4: 12
// }
```

I want to write a function `getFlag` that looks like this:

```
function getFlag(flag: keyof Flags): any { 
   // return myFlags[flag]
}
```

Instead of returning `any`, how can I return the type of flag that `getFlag` is being called with?

*(to make this maybe easier, we can limit the flag types to `boolean`, `string` and `number`, but instead of returning `boolean | string | number`, I still want to get the specific property type)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function generic so that the type of the string being passed in can be used to look up the associated type of the value on the object.

```
function getFlag<T extends keyof Flags>(flag: T) { 
   return myFlags[flag]
}
const result = getFlag('flag1');
```

You could go a step further and return the exact type with `as const`.

```
 const myFlags = {
   flag1: 'value 1',
   flag2: 'value 1',
   flag3: true,
   flag4: 12
 } as const;

function getFlag<T extends keyof typeof myFlags>(flag: T) { 
   return myFlags[flag]
}
const result = getFlag('flag1');
```

Comment: That's working perfectly. what is `as const` doing here?

Comment: It keeps the values from being widened, eg from `flag: 'value 1'` to `flag: string`, allowing for a more exact type to be used.